# Make Static menu to dynamic from arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, menuitem

I have a popup_menu.xml which has 3 item tags as static, so those 3 item values display in pop up menu, But I have one arraylist which has few values that I want to show in that popup menu.

Just I want to show carnames which is available in markersArray instead static Item values which is available in popup_menu.xml

```
Array List array 


for(int i=0; i<markersArray.size(); i++){
            String caname = markersArray.get(i).getCarname();
    }

        popup_menu.xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:title="One"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:title="Two"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:title="Three"/>
        </menu>

        MainActivity.java
         @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                // Click action
                System.out.println("Float Icon Clicked");
        //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, fab);
         //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.poupup_menu, popup.getMenu());

          //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
          popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
          public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                            }
                        });

                        popup.show();//showing popup menu

                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under this line of code

```
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, fab);
```

Just itterate through your ArrayList and add it to the popup menu like this

```
for (String s : array) {
        popup.getMenu().add(s);
    }
```